Automated determination of invariant gauge group (IGG) of spin liquid mean field ansatz
In the Abrikosov fermion mean field theory of spin liquid, the spin-1/2 operator $\mathbf{S}_i$ on each site $i$ is expressed as
$$
\mathbf{S}_i = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\alpha,\beta} 
f^\dagger_{i\alpha} \boldsymbol{\tau}_{\alpha\beta}
f_{i\beta}
$$
where $f_{i\uparrow}, f_{i\downarrow}$ are fermions, and $\boldsymbol{\tau} = (\tau^1,\tau^2,\tau^3)$ are Pauli matrices. The mean field ansatz is a matrix
$$
U_{ij} = 2 \begin{pmatrix}
    \langle f_{i\uparrow} f^\dagger_{j\uparrow} \rangle& 
    \langle f_{i\uparrow} f_{j\downarrow} \rangle
    \\
    \langle f^\dagger_{i\downarrow} f^\dagger_{j\uparrow} \rangle&
    \langle f^\dagger_{i\downarrow} f_{j\downarrow} \rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$
According to Wen Xiao-Gang's article arXiv:cond-mat/0107071, to determine the invariant gauge group (IGG) of an ansatz (i.e. the "low energy gauge structure"), we need to study the SU(2) fluxes on each closed loop $C = i \to j \to k \to \cdots \to l \to i$ (the start point $i$ is called the base point of $C$), defined as
$$
P_C = U_{ij} U_{jk} \cdots U_{li} 
$$

When $P_C \propto$ identity matrix (trivial) for all loops $C$, then IGG is still SU(2).

When $P_C$ is non-trivial, but $[P_C, P_{C'}] = 0$ when two loops $C$ and $C'$ has the same base point, then the IGG is broken to U(1).

If there exist two loops $C, C'$ such that $[P_C, P_{C'}] \ne 0$, then the IGG is broken to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.


Manually examine all possible loops for an ansatz can be difficult. I want to ask if there is an automated way (e.g. with a computer program) to do this.
